# Não define display como flex quando passa o mouse por cima

Tags: css, flexbox

Mesmo passando o mouse por cima a class `name` não aparece

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.img:hover .name {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.name {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">
    Barney
  </div>
  <img class="img" src="http://www.mamamagic.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/barney.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container:hover .name{
  display: flex;
}

.img{
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.img:hover{
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.name{
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name">Barney</div>
  <img class="img" src="http://www.mamamagic.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/barney.jpg">
</div>
```